# What words or expression can I use instead of this when talking to a cashier

Tags: word-choice

Yesterday I had 2 dollars less. Now here it is. Here you are, take these two dollars.

Comment: "*I owe you two dollars from yesterday. Here it is*".

Comment: @DanBron Why not make this an answer?

Comment: @jfhc See [this comment of mine](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2655/what-we-need-are-good-answers-it-doesnt-matter-who-writes-them#comment5422_2655) on Meta.

Comment: @DanBron that's fair enough, and I don't want to get too off-topic here, but you are still answering the question (and in a better way than the only answer posted so far)! Do answers *have to* come with justification?

Comment: @jfhc That's a better question for Meta. But my sense is it's not strictly *required*, but very strongly encouraged. Anyway, if the opinion of a native speaker is enough to satisfy OP, then my comment should suffice to meet his needs. Plus, the sole answer has updated his answer along the lines of my comment (after some feedback on his use of *lend*).

Answer (score 1):

Take the two dollars that I owe you from yesterday.

OR

Here's the two dollars that I owe you from yesterday.

Comment: It is unlikely that the cashier actually lent OP two dollars (directly); probably OP didn't have enough money to pay for his purchase, and the cashier said "don't worry, you can pay me tomorrow". Of course, in a theoretical, economic-science sense, that's identical to actual lending OP two bucks. But that's not how "lend" is employed in practice. Your phrase suggests the cashier actually handed OP two dollars; that not being the case, native speakers wouldn't phrase the repayment this way.

Comment: I think the edit I made should do the trick. The first sentence would have worked if the cashier lent the money to the person, but, yes, you're right that it wouldn't be common to say. However, you're wrong to say native speakers would not phrase a repaymen that way because it's said all the time - yes, I am a native speaker.

Comment: Whereever you're from has different pragmatics than where I am from. We say "the money you lent me" all the time, too: but only when actual money was actually lent. Underpayment in a retail context is not considered a load around these parts. But it is considered a debt (or obligation).

Comment: The problem is that there is no context here. Maybe money was exchanged, maybe it was not.

Comment: @Dan Bron - Thanks for your comments. Yes, The cashier did not lend me mony. I did not have enough money to pay. When I am paying the money the day after, you say I had better not to use the word "owe" ? Can I say what? Here's the money I didn't have yesterday.

Comment: @A.Alger When the the context of the question is not absolutely clear, it's best to make educated guesses based on realistic scenarios. The OP stated "I had two dollars less", and he was talking to a retail cashier: it is very unlikely that a cashier handed him two bucks so that (e.g.) he could go buy a sandwich somewhere else. It's possible that the cashier gave him too much change back, as an alternative, but I think that possibility is precluded by OP's assertion that he "had two dollars less".

Comment: You have to say "owe" because you "owe" the store, therefore, you "owe" the cashier. The definition of "owe" is "have an obligation to pay or repay". You have an obligation to repay.

Comment: @user5036 Yes, the store didn't "lend" you money in the traditional sense, but nevertheless you still "owe" them money. You have a debt you must repay. My original comment and A.Alger's answer here along the same lines provide appropriate phrases to communicate the situation to the cashier (whether or not the cashier is the same individual person you met yesterday; your debt is to he store, not the person).

Comment: @DanBron When cashiers check out, they have to justify their losses. Most cashiers would rather put their own money in the till to make sure the receipts and the cash match. Therefore, yes, the cashier could have put his/her money in the till and therefore you would owe the cashier.

Comment: @A.Alger Again, not where I'm from. But YMMV.

Comment: Well, when you say "take the two dollars I owe you" to the cashier, then you are basically saying "take the two dollars I owe the store", but are addressing "you" to the cashier with reference to the "store" not necessarily the cashier.

Comment: When you say "*I owe you*", the *you* refers to the store, and the cashier its agent or representative.